TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got numpy.ndarray)
I use the below code and it report error, This is a very simple example and should not report error as expected.
import numpy as np
import torch as th

# Assuming tt is some data (example as list)
tt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  # Example data

# Check if tt is a NumPy array, and convert if necessary
if not isinstance(tt, np.ndarray):
    tt = np.array(tt)

# Now, convert tt to a PyTorch tensor
tensor_tt = th.from_numpy(tt)
print(tensor_tt)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 12
      9     tt = np.array(tt)
     11 # Now, convert tt to a PyTorch tensor
---> 12 tensor_tt = th.from_numpy(tt)
     13 print(tensor_tt)

TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got numpy.ndarray)

I am using the following conda environment:
conda list
# packages in environment at /opt/miniconda3/envs/ethos:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
appnope                   0.1.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                    openblas  
bottleneck                1.3.7           py312ha86b861_0  
brotli                    1.0.9                h80987f9_8  
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h80987f9_8  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h80987f9_6  
ca-certificates           2024.9.24            hca03da5_0  
click                     8.1.7                    pypi_0    pypi
colorlog                  6.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
comm                      0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
contourpy                 1.2.0           py312h48ca7d4_0  
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
debugpy                   1.6.7           py312h313beb8_0  
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ethos                     0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
exceptiongroup            1.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.6.3                h313beb8_0  
filelock                  3.16.1                   pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.51.0          py312h80987f9_0  
freetype                  2.12.1               h1192e45_0  
fsspec                    2024.9.0                 pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      3.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        8.5.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.29.5             pyh57ce528_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.28.0             pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9e                   h80987f9_3  
jupyter_client            8.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.2              pyh31011fe_1    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py312h313beb8_0  
lcms2                     2.12                 hba8e193_0  
lerc                      3.0                  hc377ac9_0  
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h80987f9_8  
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h80987f9_8  
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h80987f9_8  
libcxx                    14.0.6               h848a8c0_0  
libdeflate                1.17                 h80987f9_1  
libffi                    3.4.4                hca03da5_1  
libgfortran               5.0.0           11_3_0_hca03da5_28  
libgfortran5              11.3.0              h009349e_28  
libopenblas               0.3.21               h269037a_0  
libpng                    1.6.39               h80987f9_0  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h27ca646_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.1                h313beb8_0  
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h80987f9_0  
llvm-openmp               14.0.6               hc6e5704_0  
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h313beb8_1  
markupsafe                2.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-base           3.9.2           py312h2df2da3_0  
matplotlib-inline         0.1.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.4                  h313beb8_0  
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.3                      pypi_0    pypi
numexpr                   2.8.7           py312h0f3ea24_0  
numpy                     2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.26.4          py312he047099_0  
openjpeg                  2.5.2                h54b8e55_0  
openssl                   3.3.2                h8359307_0    conda-forge
packaging                 24.1               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    2.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
parso                     0.8.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    10.4.0          py312h80987f9_0  
pip                       24.2            py312hca03da5_0  
platformdirs              4.3.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.48             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.0           py312h80987f9_0  
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   17.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.18.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.1.2           py312hca03da5_0  
python                    3.12.7               h99e199e_0  
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0              pypi_0    pypi
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pytz                      2024.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py312h313beb8_0  
readline                  8.2                  h1a28f6b_0  
seaborn                   0.13.2                   pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                75.1.0          py312hca03da5_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.45.3               h80987f9_0  
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.13.3                   pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.14               h6ba3021_0  
torch                     2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tornado                   6.4.1           py312h80987f9_0  
tqdm                      4.66.5                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.14.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.12.2             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2024.2                   pypi_0    pypi
unicodedata2              15.1.0          py312h80987f9_0  
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.44.0          py312hca03da5_0  
xz                        5.4.6                h80987f9_1  
zeromq                    4.3.5                h313beb8_0  
zipp                      3.20.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h18a0788_1  
zstd                      1.5.5                hd90d995_2  


I try to convert np.array data to tensor in torch; The reporting error is confusing; I do not know whether there is conflicting in the package versions.
When I downgrade the numpy it still report the same error:
import numpy as np
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
print(np.__version__)
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=np.float32)
y = torch.from_numpy(x)

2.4.1
1.26.0
{
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "expected np.ndarray (got numpy.ndarray)",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 6
      4 print(np.__version__)
      5 x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], dtype=np.float32)
----> 6 y = torch.from_numpy(x)

TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got numpy.ndarray)"
}



After a number of trials I figure out why there is problem.
Note that there are two numpy versions numpy (1.26.4) and numpy-base (2.1.2) in the installation. If you uninstall numpy (1.26.4) and then reinstall by conda install numpy==1.26.0, your error will remain; what you need to do is to pip uninstall numpy again to ensure the version 2.1.2 is also removed.

You interchanged the numpy versions.
Worked for me.
Additional info, If numpy was installed via conda. Then pip uninstall numpy twice, to remove numpy-base. Then reinstall with conda install numpy==. Conda will not do anything if you specify same version.

This is a known error, you need to uninstall numpy by:
pip uninstall numpy

then install "numpy<1.26.4" afresh.
pip install "numpy<1.26.4"

References:
https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/issues/9069#issuecomment-2267596351
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/135836#issuecomment-2347209235

that seems not workable for me, it report the same error when using the 1.26.0 version of the numpy

What is your torch version ?

my torch version is 2.4.1
